# file association problem

Tags: windows-7

i chnaged a file with association COMMOR to cmd.exe. Now i can not REDO this action and when right clicking the file, and chosing the PROPERTIES, the CHANGE button is not there?
please help me on this issue

Comment: Hold down Shift and choose Open with from the right-click menu.

Comment: open with... is standard in Win7, meaning you dont need to hold shift down.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file, then click "Open with..." and select the correct program.  If you dont see any other programs listed make sure you click on the arrow at the end of the line where it says "other programs".  That got me the first few times when I started with Win7.